# Pylint: check similarity for one file against module

Tags: python, pylint

There is a similarity checker in pylint that cross checking duplicate code in a given module.
The motive is to ensure no or limited code duplication is made by the new code.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I have a feeling it is too broad.

Comment: For instance there is a new python file is going to be committed, I would like to know if the new feature already implemented somewhere in a give module to prevent code duplication. If a python project with over 100KLOC, it is pretty hard to know if similar function already been implemented.